# I need to make an input field overflow a td without changing its position or the tds width using CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I need to enlarge an input field when it's on focus without the containing td enlarging, too.

Further on both fields should stay on their actual position (have a look on the fiddle, it mooves) and not move up or down (what is caused by the absolute position).

This is my actual state

```
    $('.Bemerkung').focus(function() {
    $(this).attr('size','30');
    $(this).parent().css({'position':'absolute'});
    $(this).css({'position':'absolute'});
})
$('.Bemerkung').blur(function() {
    $(this).attr('size','5');
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
    $(this).parent().removeAttr('style');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kazuya88/dhy0dxyy/

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Doesn't look like it moves to me in Chrome.

Comment: I'm using Chrome and the textbox goes out of the table on focus.
Are you trying to make the textbox wider on focus and not change the width of the column?

Comment: I updated the fiddle - if you have a row with 2 lines the inputs moves more clearly to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not too far from  what you originally had:

```
$('.Bemerkung').focus(function() {
    oldWidth = $(this).width();
    $(this).attr('size','30');
    $(this).css({'position':'relative'});
    $(this).css({'margin-right':('-'+($(this).width()-oldWidth)+'px')});
})
$('.Bemerkung').blur(function() {
    $(this).attr('size','5');
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
    $(this).parent().removeAttr('style');
})
```

Update: I figured I should add more explanation about what is going on here. This basically detects what the size is before gaining focus, then increases the size and sets the right margin to the difference between the new size and the old size (thus making the renderer see it as the same "width" as before gaining focus). Position:relative is so that the element width will not affect the td width (as long as right-margin is set negative).

Comment: Note that this allows you to keep your center alignment. FYI, here's a diff of your old code and the code above: http://www.filediff.net/d/O2oS07sIqU/

Answer (score 1):

You could use `transform: scale(1.2)` to enlarge it, add `transition` and remove `absolute` position declarations.

```js
$('.Bemerkung').focus(function() {
  $(this).css({
    'transition': 'transform 0.5s',
    'transform': 'scale(1.2)'
  });
});
$('.Bemerkung').blur(function() {
  $(this).css({
    'transform': 'scale(1)'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="weektimereg" class="recordlist" border=1 style="text-align:center;">
  <tr>
    <th style="width:110px;">sample</th>
    <th style="width:110px;">sample2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type=text size=3 name=abc value='03:00'></input>
      <input class='Bemerkung' type=text size=5 name=cde value='test'></input>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type=text size=3 name=abc value='03:00'></input>
      <input class='Bemerkung' type=text size=5 name=cde value='test'></input>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type=text size=3 name=abc value='03:00'></input>
      <input class='Bemerkung' type=text size=5 name=cde value='test'></input>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type=text size=3 name=abc value='03:00'></input>
      <input class='Bemerkung' type=text size=5 name=cde value='test'></input>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the javascript with strict CSS.

One thing i did was make the td cell text-align: left. that's the only real difference right now. The reason there is movement when you switch to an absolute position is due to the fact that it's trying to align the elements to the center, but then absolute elements don't get measured or centered.

Here is the CSS.

```
table td{
position: relative;
overflow: visible;
text-align: left;
}

.Bemerkung:focus{
    width: 196px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Let me know if you need to text-align: center and i'll look for a different solution.